# How do I find :$b a^2+ c b^2+ a c^2$ according to below given conditions?

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

Let $a,b,c>0$ such that:
$a+b+c=5$ and

$ \frac 1a +b+\frac 1b +c+ \frac 1c +a=9/10.$

I have tried to find the value of :$b a^2+ c b^2+ a c^2$ using the above  gaven but i didn't succeed however i have added a third equality which is :$(a+b+c)^2=25$ but no result

My question is to find :

$b a^2+ c b^2+ a c^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your two equations imply:

$\frac{9}{10} = \frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b}+c+\frac{1}{c}+a = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+ (a+b+c) = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} + 5.$

Thus $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = \frac{9}{10}-5 = \frac{9}{10}-\frac{50}{10}<0$.  Since you also state that $a,b,c>0$, there can be no numbers $a,b,c$ meeting your initial conditions.

Comment: I know that but i don't seek for a, b, c as independent values look what i want in the question

Comment: You asked to find the value of $ba^2+cb^2+ac^2$ given three constraints.  I'm pointing out that there can be no numbers meeting those constraints at the same time.

Comment: I will say one more thing.  If you are willing to drop the restriction that a,b, and c are all positive, then you can find solutions.  Mathematica, Sage, and even the free website Wolfram Alpha produces it.